# Angular 4 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, routes

1. I have AppModule as below -

   ```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
   import { Router } from '@angular/router';
   import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

   @NgModule({
     declarations: [
       AppComponent
     ],
     imports: [
       BrowserModule,AppRoutingModule
     ],
     providers: [],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```
2. My AppRoutingModule is like below -

   ````
   import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

   const routes: Routes = [
           {
           path: '',
           loadChildren: './skeleton/main/main.module#MainModule',
       },
   ];

   @NgModule({
       imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
       exports: [RouterModule]
   })
   export class AppRoutingModule {}```
   ````
3. MainModule -

   ````
   import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
   import { MainComponent } from './main.component';

   @NgModule({
     imports: [
       CommonModule
     ],
     declarations: [MainComponent]
   })
   export class MainModule {}```
   ````
4. app.component.html is like below

   `< router-outlet > < /router-outlet >`
5. main.component.html -

   `< h1 > main works! < /h1 >`

when I am starting application, I am getting the following error:-

```
core.js:1427 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:130)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:108)
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.OuterSubscriber.notifyError (OuterSubscriber.js:24)
    at InnerSubscriber._error (InnerSubscriber.js:28)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:130)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:108)
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at FirstSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.OuterSubscriber.notifyError (OuterSubscriber.js:24)
    at InnerSubscriber._error (InnerSubscriber.js:28)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:821)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:785)
    at eval (zone.js:870)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4744)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:594)
    at <anonymous>
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1427
ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1488
next @ core.js:5498
schedulerFn @ core.js:4339
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:240
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:187
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:128
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:92
Subject.next @ Subject.js:56
EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:4319
(anonymous) @ core.js:4775
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
Zone.run @ zone.js:138
NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:4701
onHandleError @ core.js:4775
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:392
Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:154
_loop_1 @ zone.js:692
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:701
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:602
Promise resolved (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:577
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:868
resolvePromise @ zone.js:815
(anonymous) @ zone.js:736
webpackJsonpCallback @ inline.bundle.js:22
(anonymous) @ main.module.chunk.js:1
core.js:1427 ERROR RangeError: M
```

Why I am getting this error as there is no loop in my code?

Comment: Can you add MainModule?

Comment: Try adding forChild configuration in MainModule

Comment: `RouterModule.forChild({ path: '', component: MainComponent })`

Answer (score 5):

You would need to add a routing module inside of the mainModule for the main module route. For example.

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {Routes, RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {MainComponent} from "./main.component"

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MainRoutingModule {}
```

Then include the routing module in your MainModule

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import {AppointmentComponent} from '../../components/views/appointment/appointment.component';
import {ComponentsModule} from '../../components/components.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomePage
  }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [HomePage, AppointmentComponent]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message with a different issue, using Ionic (though it could happen with Angular only too): inside a page (which is an Angular component) called ***chat-list*** I put a component also called ***chat-list***, meaning both of them had the same ***app-chat-list*** selector, which caused an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and things even gone wrong on startup if I had the `{preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules}`enabled.

The problem was that I had a cyclic dependency due to a children module which for some reason imported the parent one.

To quickly find from where the issue came, I used madge

```sh
npm i -g madge
madge --circular --extensions ts ./
```

In my case I got the following output:

```sh
✖ Found 1 circular dependency!

1) app/features/customer/customer.module.ts > app/features/customer/customer-routing.module.ts > app/features/customer/create/create.module.ts
```

Meaning create.module.ts was importing something from customer.module.ts (and conversely). Removing the useless import fixed the issue.